# mplayer can't play audio from cron while ncmpcpp is playing simultaneously

Tags: scripts, cron, mplayer, mpd, ncmpcpp

I have set up a script, which executes an mplayer command, in order to play audio in crontab. It will be executed in a special set time, but this script can not play audio when ncmpcpp (a front-end for mpd, aka. Music Player Daemon) is playing music. But this script can play audio when I execute it from terminal like this:

```
sh bin/alarm.sh
```

I try to get output from either crontab or script, but to no avail. I guess some setting in ncmpcpp or mplayer is wrong, or mpd is using same daemon with crontab's daemon.

- Anyway, I can not find out the solution. If you know, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that mpd runs under user mpd per default (as a system daemon) and is thus unable to join your sessions' pulseaudio mixer, therefore it hogs the sound card output via alsa or even oss. In my answer, I assume that you are logged in and that the crontab is yours and not the system crontab.

### MPD

Depending on your priorities, you have a lot of options that mostly circle around the idea teaching mpd to not hog the sound and use pulseaudio instead. See the [mpd wiki](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/PulseAudio).

### mplayer

You can configure mplayer to default to pulseaudio by placing a line `ao=pulse` in `~/.mplayer/config` but pulseaudio should pick it up nicely with its alsa plugin.

Comment: I have set `ao=pulse` in `~/.mplayer/config`. but set mpd on pulseaudio is so complex. But it this splution is good.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `mplayer` just waits until `mpd` is paused, then plays the sound.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped with a Qt5 app which was refusing to play while an `mplayer` instance was running - turns out `mplayer` hogged the sound device. Setting it to `pulse` allowed them to share it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your crontab, please add this to the command section

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && sh /bin/alarm.sh
```

The `export DISPLAY=:0.0` is required to run Graphical apps.

Comment: It does not help for sound though.. the error from cron for e.g. ogg123 is: `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ERROR: Cannot open device alsa.`

Answer (score 0):

When using e.g. `play` (from the `sox` package), the following information needs to be exported:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) <sound command>
```

Also have a look at the links below, as other vars might be needed:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Play_sound_from_a_non-interactive_shell_.28systemd_service.2C_cron.29

[mplayer can't play audio from cron while ncmpcpp is playing simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64033/mplayer-cant-play-audio-from-cron-while-ncmpcpp-is-playing-simultaneously/988043#988043)

Comment: Please [edit] and explain where/how this variable should be passed or set, and if possible why it is needed